# How to create empty rows on user creation in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authentication

i am using PHP Codeigniter.In this i have a Table **Retailer** in which i have a field No of Users required by the Retailer. Is it possible that when admin creates the retailer the value he inserted in the field no of users, that much rows must be created in another table **User**. I just want to create that much empty rows in the user table which are mapped to the retailer id.The users in user table have one field **Key** which must be the unique key of retailer. I am new to codeigniter and dont have any logic how to do this. 
Following is my code to create a retailer :
Controller Code:

```
<?php
```

class Reseller extends Admin_Controller
{

```
public function __construct ()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index ()
{
    // Fetch all users
    $this->data['users'] = $this->reseller_m->get();

    // Load view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/reseller/index';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}
    public function reseller ()
{
    // Fetch all users
    $this->data['users'] = $this->reseller_m->get();

    // Load view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/reseller/users'; //Users variable stores the suvbview 
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}


public function edit ($id = NULL)
{
    // Fetch a user or set a new one
    if ($id) {
        $this->data['user'] = $this->reseller_m->get($id);
        count($this->data['user']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'User could not be found';
    }
    else {
        $this->data['user'] = $this->reseller_m->get_new();
    }

    // Set up the form
    $rules = $this->reseller_m->rules_admin;
    $id || $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

    // Process the form
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
```

$data = $this->reseller_m->array_from_post(array('sip_username','sip_password','key','allocation_block','name','email','password','phone','balance','user_num','address','country','created','modified','status'));

```
        $data['password'] = $this->reseller_m->hash($data['password']);


        $key=$this->reseller_m->save($data, $id);
        for($i=1; $i<=$data['user_num'];$i++)
            {
            $userdata=array('key'=>$key);
        // here users is taken name of user table with retailer_id is field
            $this->db->insert('users',$userdata);
             }



        redirect('admin/reseller');
    }

    // Load the view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/reseller/edit';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}


public function delete ($id)
{
    $this->reseller_m->delete($id);
    redirect('admin/reseller');
}
```

}

The Model:

```
<?php
```

class Reseller_M extends MY_Model
{

```
protected $_table_name = 'reseller';
protected $_order_by = 'name';
protected $_timestamps = TRUE;
public $rules = array(
    'email' => array(
        'field' => 'email', 
        'label' => 'Email', 
        'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean'
    ), 
    'password' => array(
        'field' => 'password', 
        'label' => 'Password', 
        'rules' => 'trim|required'
    ),

);
public $rules_admin = array(
    'name' => array(
        'field' => 'name', 
        'label' => 'Name', 
        'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
    ), 
    'email' => array(
        'field' => 'email', 
        'label' => 'Email', 
        'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|callback__unique_email|xss_clean'
    ), 
    'password' => array(
        'field' => 'password', 
        'label' => 'Password', 
        'rules' => 'trim|matches[password_confirm]'
    ),
    'password_confirm' => array(
        'field' => 'password_confirm', 
        'label' => 'Confirm password', 
        'rules' => 'trim|matches[password]'
    ),
    'sip_username' => array(
        'field' => 'sip_username', 
        'label' => 'Sip Username', 
        'rules' => 'trim|required|'
    ),
    'sip_password' => array(
        'field' => 'sip_password', 
        'label' => 'SIP Password', 
        'rules' => 'trim|required|'
    ),


);

function __construct ()
{
    parent::__construct();

}




public function get_new(){
    $user = new stdClass();

//          $user->id = '';
    $user->sip_username='';
    $user->sip_password='';
    $user->key='';
    $user->allocation_block='';
    $user->name='';
    $user->email = '';      
    $user->password = '';
    $user->phone=''; 
    $user->user_num=''; 
    $user->address = '';
    $user->status = '';
    $user->country=''; 
    $user->created = '';
    $user->modified  = '';
    $user->balance = '';
    return $user;
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);

}

public function get_user_profile(){
    $this->db->select('id,sip_password,sip_username,phone,key,address,country,created,modified,user_num,allocation_block,status,email, name, balance');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('reseller', array('id' => $this->session->userdata('id')));
    return $query->result();
}






public function hash ($string)
{
    return hash('sha512', $string . config_item('encryption_key'));
}


public function loggedin ()
{
    return (bool) $this->session->userdata('loggedin');
}
```

}

the Base model:

```
<?php
```

class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

```
protected $_table_name = '';
protected $_primary_key = 'id';
protected $_primary_filter = 'intval';
protected $_order_by = '';
public $rules = array();
protected $_timestamps = FALSE;

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function array_from_post($fields){
    $data = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $data[$field] = $this->input->post($field);
    }
    return $data;
}


public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE){

    if ($id != NULL) {
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $method = 'row';
    }
    elseif($single == TRUE) {
        $method = 'row';
    }
    else {
        $method = 'result';
    }


    return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();
}

public function get_by($where, $single = FALSE){
    $this->db->where($where);
    return $this->get(NULL, $single);
}

public function save($data, $id = NULL){


    $this->db->cache_on();

    // Set timestamps
    if ($this->_timestamps == TRUE) {
        $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $id || $data['created'] = $now;
        $data['modified'] = $now;
    }

    // Insert
    if ($id === NULL) {
        !isset($data[$this->_primary_key]) || $data[$this->_primary_key] = NULL;
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->insert($this->_table_name);
        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    // Update
    else {
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $this->db->update($this->_table_name);
    }

    return $id;
}

public function delete($id){
    $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
    $id = $filter($id);

    if (!$id) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $this->db->delete($this->_table_name);
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you want to make an empty rows

Comment: insert one unique id for each row to differentiate and then replace your retails with that unique id , this is codeiginiter framework

Comment: @ArunYokesh i think i should do a for loop at the time of retailer creation but i dont know how to do and where to do!

Comment: @Uchiha I want to let the retailer add other details. the admin will provide only the username and password. So when reseller is created there would be empty rows created with just username and password with other blank fields

Comment: please post your reseller_m save function and then I will modify and let you know where to change

Comment: @shanusingh this i have created a base model where all the data is saved. i have added its code in the question. see the updated question

Comment: please check my answer and changes made in your controller function

Comment: Okay i will try this. Thank you

Comment: @shanusingh the code you gave me it inserts the values that insert in reseller field. What i mean to say is when i insert a reseller,i fill up some details and have one field user_num which is the no of users requested by him. He would have an access to those users. So i want to insert a blank row in users table but just want those rows to be mapped with the reseller_id i hope you get me

Comment: @shanusingh the code you gave me it inserts the values that are inserted in reseller field. What i mean to say is when i insert a reseller,i fill up some details and have one field user_num which is the no of users requested by him to be genrated. reseller would have an access to those users. So i want to insert a blank row in users table but just want those rows to be mapped with the reseller_id i hope you get me

Comment: @shanusingh can you please explain me your code. i did'nt failed to understand. So please. As i want to generate key of reseller based in the information he has given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify following function as bellow.

```
  public function edit ($id = NULL)
 {
// Fetch a user or set a new one
if ($id) {
    $this->data['user'] = $this->reseller_m->get($id);
    count($this->data['user']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'User could not be found';
}
else {
    $this->data['user'] = $this->reseller_m->get_new();
}

// Set up the form
$rules = $this->reseller_m->rules_admin;
$id || $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required';
$this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

// Process the form
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
    $data = $this->reseller_m->array_from_post(array('sip_username','sip_password','key','allocation_block','name','email', 'password','phone','user_num','address','status','country','created','modified','balance'));
    $data['password'] = $this->reseller_m->hash($data['password']);
    //modify here
    $retailer_id=$this->reseller_m->save($data, $id); 
    for($i=1; $i<=$data['user_num'],$i++)
    {
        $userdata=array('retailer_id'=>$retailer_id);
        // here users is taken name of user table with retailer_id is field
        $this->db->insert('users',$userdata);
    }

    redirect('admin/reseller');
 }

  // Load the view
  $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/reseller/edit';
  $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
 }
```

Comment: the code you gave me it inserts the values that are inserted in reseller field. What i mean to say is when i insert a reseller,i fill up some details and have one field user_num which is the no of users requested by him. He would have an access to those users. So i want to insert a blank row in users table but just want those rows to be mapped with the reseller_id i hope you get me

Comment: //modify here
    $retailer_id=$this->reseller_m->save($data, $id); 
    for($i=1; $i<=$data['user_num'],$i++)
    {
        $userdata=array('retailer_id'=>$retailer_id);
        // here users is taken name of user table with retailer_id is field
        $this->db->insert('users',$userdata);
    } 
this will do that, just change table name and field name according to your table

Comment: @shanusigh i have changed the credentials also it creates the users dynamically, but for eg i inserted 10 as user_num. So what it did was created duplicated 8 rows in my reseller table and two rows in users table. also the users table should be blank except the key(uniuqe id of reseller)

Comment: if user_num is 10 then it will insert 10 rows in user  table with user primary key and reseller_id, if you wish to add other field then you can modify it acccording to that.

Comment: yes it should do as you commented but instead what it does is insertes 8 records in reseller table and 2 records in users table. i have updated the question code.. please check the edit method and tell me where i am going wrong

Comment: sorry my mistake it does create the users as i want but there is a little bug. it creates duplicate records in reseller table for the same reseller 8 times

Comment: $this->generate_m->save($data2,$id); change this with $this->generate_m->save($userdata,$id);, but please check this function is related to user table

Comment: i am getting following error :Unknown column 'reseller_id' in 'field list'

Comment: change it as per user table field name and make sure that save function call user table otherwise use my code $this->db->insert('tablename',$userdata)

Comment: i used your code but got the same error Unknown column 'reseller_id' in 'field list'

Comment: i agree it works but its creating multiple fields in the reseller field as well, how to solve that? and Thank you very very much for this help its really appreciated

Comment: really sorry but i had written duplicate line to save data so it was saving multiple records thanks a lot your code worked as charm thank you very much

Comment: can i ask for a little more help? i am generating a key for reseller and i want to map this key with the user generated instead of the reseller_id ! will you please help me

Comment: shanusingh please help.. the code you gave me works. but everytime i edit a reseller it creates a user in database so how to fix this bug?

Comment: @rajan, please share your current code of controller, I have seen right now posted and found that instead of $userdata, you used $data2 in insert and that is wrong. please change that to $userdata in line $this->generate_m->save($data2,$id); and also share model generate_m to me.

Comment: i have updated the reseller Controller code and its Model is reseller_m instead of genrate_m. so  please go through it and let me know my mistake

Comment: Hello Can you Please Help Me With This :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266975/how-to-deduct-balance-from-reseller-dynamically-in-php-codeigniter